# Sontronics users?

Tags: equipment, microphone

Hi y'all.

As many of you I'm trying to gather information on what mics to buy. I've spotted the Sontronics line of small condenser mics and they're insanely cheap. Too insane? Has anyone ever seen/read/heard any reviews on the STC-10 for recording dialogue or other things than acoustic guitar? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi Olle
STC-10 was designed specifically by Trevor for musicians on a tight budget, and is based on exactly the same technology and cardioid capsule found in our STC-1 - http://www.sontronics.com/stc1.htm

The savings mainly come in the fact that it doesn't have a flightcase or wooden box like our other (slightly) more expensive mics. But STC-10 still gives you a two-stage pad switch (0dB/-10dB) and two-stage pad (0Hz/75Hz), and comes with a mic clip and windshield.

All our recommendations for usage of our microphones is based on real user experiences, and we know that it does a fantastic job on acoustic guitar or any other plucked strings (sitar, banjo, bouzouki, etc) and direct miking of drums and percussion. It also works well on most stringed instruments - violin and cello especially - and woodwind, and we also have people using it for film and video production work, on a boom.

I don't know how your German is, but here's a review of the STC-10 and the STC-20 (our budget large-diaphragm condenser mic). http://www.sontronics.com/files/2010_05_recordingmagazin_test_sontronics_stc10_stc20.pdf

The next step up is the STC-1 (also available in a stereo pair - STC-1S) and for the extra cost you get a three-stage pad, three-stage filter and a wooden carry case.

Let us know if you need any more info, and I'll see if I can dig up some more reviews for you. Good luck!

Lisa (lisa@sontronics.com)

Comment: Hi Lisa! I'm so glad that you wrote on here with a personal response. That's very reassuring! I've never heard of that kind of customer service! Great stuff! Now I'm convinced o try buying one. I will pst a hands-on review and video tests as soon as I get my hands on one.

Thank you once again Lisa! 

Answer (score 1):

So, I went to my Sontronics dealer here in Sweden to get an STC-10, they didn't have it in stock but they did have one STC-1 that they were kind enough to lend me. 
My expectations were high, the salesman told me all about their enormous amount of happy customers. So I went out with a happy face, come home, plug the mic in and still smiling.

It's really, really nice. A bargain. More than a bargain, it's almost legal robbery.My experience is that it's got a nice open airy sound, not noisy as I would have imagined it to be. The specs are really good, but really I don't care. It sounds good and that's good enough. 
If someone had told me it 5 times the price I would probably have believed in them and probably gone and bought it if it weren't for one thing; size and weight.
Not a big issue, but for me it was at this time. I will definitely go out and get me a pair of STC-1s around christmas, but right now my need is for smaller mics, and there are several to choose from with similar features and characteristics.

It isn't humongous for a microphone, but for my needs (I want to be able to put two mics in one blimp/zeppelin) it is. And also the weight is a bit of an issue if I were to boom with it. It would work, but it'd be heavy. And it would also require me to buy extra shockmounts and an extra blimp/zeppelin so economically it's not worth it right now, but in the future OMG.

This is easily the best mic in this price range that I've laid hands on, and I have to admit that's not many. I haven't actually seen a mic with these specs and features in this price range.

I also got a chance to try the hyper-cardioid capsule. Not as clear and airy as the cardioid one naturally... But it did the job pretty good for this price!

In conclusion, the STC-1 if a definite buy for me, just not right now. I will buy a pair of STC-1s however and not the STC-10, for the size and weight. STC-1 will be of great use for ADR, "Colored Foley" (like for outdoors or distant foley with some coloration) and effects recording. Works great for outdoor ambiances!

If there's anyone wondering anything more, contact me on olle@tjockishjartafilm.se. I have some audio clips as well. And some video of me babbling on.

Great stuff, and thanks for the reply again Lisa.